# ARM assembly like program to Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, methods

This is what my code is so far. I searched for some links but have no idea if they are right [such as this one](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/java-arithmetic-operators/)

```
   if( op == addCode) {
      a = b + c;
      *should I return something?*
  }
  else if (op == subCode){
      a = b - c;
      *should I return something?*
  }
  else if (op == multCode){
      a = b * c;
      *should I return something?*
  }
  else if (op == divCode){
      a = b / c;
     *should I return something?*
  }
  else if (op == remCode){
      a = b % c;
      *should I return something?*
  }
  else if (op == equalCode){
      if( b == c){
         **not sure what to do here**
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("The numbers are not equal");
      }

  }
  else if (op ==notEqualCode){

      if (b != c){
          **not sure what to do here**
      }
      else {
      System.out.print("The numbers are are equal");
      }
  }
  else if (op == lessCode){
      if (b < c){
          **not sure what to do here**
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("The numbers is not less than each other");
      }
  }
  else if (op == lessEqualCode){
      if (b <= c){
         **not sure what to do here**
      }
      else{
      System.out.println("The numbers is not less than or equal to each other");
      }


}
```

---

```
9 a b c     add         Add the values in cell b and cell c and store the 
result in cell a. 
10 a b c        subtract            Same as 9, but do cell b − cell c. 
11 a b c        multiply            Same as 9, but do cell b ∗ cell c. 
12 a b c        divide          Same as 9, but do cell b / cell c.
13 a b c        remainder       Same as 9, but do cell b % cell c. 
14 a b c        equal           Same as 9, but do cell b == cell c. 
15 a b c        not equal       Same as 9, but do cell b != cell c. 
16 a b c        less than       Same as 9, but do cell b < cell c. 
17 a b c        less than or equal      Same as 9, but do cell b <= cell c
```

I was trying to change this ARM like coding into Java. But it does not seem like I got my arithmetic wrong. I also can not return int as the main program returns void so there's a restriction. Everything is initialized as a private, and the op code should correspond with the following operations.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly your question is? Because it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm trying to see if my arithmetic is right, and to see if my translation from this language to Java is correct. Because I don't think my arithmetic translation is right.

Comment: I don't see any ARM asm in your question.  You appear to already have Java code that uses a series of conditions instead of a `switch` to decide what to do.  If it doesn't do what you want, then explain in English what you *do* want it to do.